# Trying to insert a value containing a ';' in MySQL, how do I do that?

Tags: mysql

I was tryin to insert into MySQL the following code:

`<img src='http://romaniaz.net/forumz/styles/SE_Gamer_Dark/imageset/logo.png' alt='' style='width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left; margin: 20px'>`

but it wouldn't allow me since I'm using the `;` symbol. How can I insert such values in MySQL ? I read about `DELIMITER` but it's the most confusing thing I ever came across.

Edit:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO blog_posts (PostTitle, PostBody, PostAuthor, PostDate, PostTags, views) VALUES (
        '" . $title . "',
        '" . $blogpost . "',
        '" . $author . "',
        '" . $date . "',
        '" . $tags . "',
        '" . $views . "')");
```

And yes, I'm aware I have to switch from `mysql_*`.

So the problem is the $blogpost contains images with HTML style tag and automatically contains one or more semicolons...

Comment: Use *Prepared Statements* in the programming language you use and it will be done automatically for you.

Comment: Please show us how you are “tryin to insert into MySQL”.

Comment: Its not the semi-colon ; causing the issue, I think it is the single-quotes. Try double quotes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not the semi-colon that is causing issue, it is the single-quotes in HTML. Either escape them with two single quotes or use double quotes:

Escaped:

```
<img src=''http://romaniaz.net/forumz/styles/SE_Gamer_Dark/imageset/logo.png'' alt='''' style=''width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left; margin: 20px''>
```

Double Quotes:

```
<img src="http://romaniaz.net/forumz/styles/SE_Gamer_Dark/imageset/logo.png" alt="" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left; margin: 20px">
```

Answer (score 2):

@Nawed Khan is correct, this has nothing to do with semicolons being supported or not. Semicolons inside strings are not special to SQL. But your string has single-quotes in it, which is terminating the single-quote delimiting string in your SQL.

A simpler textbook case is trying to insert an Irish name:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (name) VALUES ('O'Reilly')
```

The apostrophe inside O'Reilly ends the string, so the content following doesn't make any sense to SQL.  The fix is to escape the apostrophe so it counts only as a character, not a string termination.

```
INSERT INTO mytable (name) VALUES ('O\'Reilly')
```

Standard SQL also allows the same thing to be done by double the single-quote character. MySQL supports this, but for some reason it isn't used as much anymore.

```
INSERT INTO mytable (name) VALUES ('O''Reilly')
```

The way to solve this with the ext/mysql API is to use mysql_real_escape_string(). This finds the troublesome characters and escapes them with the backslashing method.

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string("<img src='http://romaniaz.net/forumz/styles/SE_Gamer_Dark/imageset/logo.png' alt='' style='width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left; margin: 20px'>");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO blog_posts (PostTitle, ...)
 VALUES ('$title', ...");
```

Note that you don't have to break out of the double-quoted PHP string to put the value of simple PHP variables inside that string.

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, that query can be rewritten this way...

```
"
INSERT INTO blog_posts 
(PostTitle
, PostBody
, PostAuthor
, PostDate
, PostTags
, views) VALUES 
('$title'
,'$blogpost'
,'$author'
,'$date'
,'$tags'
,'$views'
);
";
```